# Is the difference of sets of a semiring in the semiring itself

Tags: real-analysis

For a semiring $\mathcal{H} $ of sets one of the requirements is that for $A,B \in \mathcal{H}$ there exist disjoint sets $C_1, C_2,...,C_n$ such that $A\setminus B = \cup_{i=1}^n C_i.$ It is unclear if it is meant for $A\setminus B$ to be in the semiring or not. Given that the property of being closed under finite unions is not a requirement in the definition of a semiring, one may expect that the difference must not be in general in the semiring. In the case of right half open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $[a,b)$, the difference will be in the semiring, but I do not have an example to show an opposite case, in which the difference of sets in the semiring is not in the semiring. Can you provide a reference or a proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $S=\{(a,b]:a\in\mathbb{R}, b\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

$(0,3]\in S$, $(1,2]\in S$ but $(0,3]\backslash(1,2]=(0,1]\cup(2,3]\notin S$.